# Adding additional filed in unix file based on another field in the respective row of same file

Tags: awk

I want to add another field as last column which will be calculated from the third field of each row. I am using the below command and able to get the desired output but instead of hardcoded value "1534625333" I want to pass the $3, but since $3 here comes as part of awk command hence in system function it is not recognized. Could anyone please help how can we make $3 visible in system() as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

abc.txt

> 18552143176|484537|1534575204|2018-08-17|23:53:24|0|0.025862||123
>   22398615839|484537|1534623829|2018-08-18|13:23:49|0|0.025862||123
>   16315832000|484895|1534562313|2018-08-17|23:18:33|0|0.702858||123
>   43995679934|484895|1534572260|2018-08-18|02:04:20|21|0.702858||123
>   11185713954|485598|1534614075|2018-08-18|13:41:15|3587|0.022928||267

`awk -F"|" '{printf("%s|%s",$0,system("date -d @1534625333 +%Y%m%d"))}' abc.csv`

Desired Output

> 18552143176|484537|1534575204|2018-08-17|23:53:24|0|0.025862||123|20180818
>   22398615839|484537|1534623829|2018-08-18|13:23:49|0|0.025862||123|20180818
>   16315832000|484895|1534562313|2018-08-17|23:18:33|0|0.702858||123|20180817
>   43995679934|484895|1534572260|2018-08-18|02:04:20|21|0.702858||123|20180818
>   11185713954|485598|1534614075|2018-08-18|13:41:15|3587|0.022928||267|20180818

Comment: I tried using this:
/usr/bin/gawk -F"|" '{var=system("date -d @"$2" +%Y%m%d");printf("%s|%s",$0,var)}' nofile
But the printing seemed to appear out of sequence (probably related to the system call occurring out of step, but needs an expert to confirm.  For this INPUT:
aa|1534575204|bbb
cc|1|dd
Results: 
20180818
aa|1534575204|bbb|019700101
cc|1|dd|0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$(NF+1)=strftime("%Y%m%d",$3)} 1' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for instant help.